# Pulling Through The Full Key:Value API Details From Geonames

Tags: php, geonames

I just want to know how to find out the API root field to pull through all of the information correctly.

I have tried searching through http://www.geonames.org/source-code/javadoc/src-html/org/geonames/WebService.html and pulled the root from:

Element root = connectAndParse(url);
1731                for (Object obj : root.getChildren("timezone"))

but this does not return anything and gives me the error of: **Undefined array key "timezone"**

If i replace timezone with sunrise then I only get through : **"2021-08-15 06:15"**, which is part of the information and can replace the key to receive one value through at at time.

How can I get the full details through?

```
<?php

    //Timezone

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $url='http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=' . $_REQUEST['lat'] . '&lng=' . $_REQUEST['lng'] . '&username=simonjadams';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);    

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode['timezone'];
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 

?>
```

The geonames API details are

Timezone
Webservice Type : REST
Url : api.geonames.org/timezone?
Parameters : lat,lng, radius (buffer in km for closest timezone in coastal areas),lang (for countryName), date (date for sunrise/sunset);
Result : the timezone at the lat/lng with gmt offset (1. January) and dst offset (1. July)
Example http://api.geonames.org/timezone?lat=47.01&lng=10.2&username=demo

This service is also available in JSON format : http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=47.01&lng=10.2&username=demo

Comment: first: the daily limit of 20000 credits for demo has been exceeded
If you want to know specifics about an API, read the documentation.
No one will be able to help you debug a paid API.

Comment: Hello, i'm using &username=simonjadams as the account (shown in the code above). It's a free GeoNames account and not a paid one.

Answer (score 0):

### Examining the API

When I requested the URL you gave as an exaple I got the following result:

```json
{
    "sunrise": "2021-08-16 06:16",
    "lng": 10.2,
    "countryCode": "AT",
    "gmtOffset": 1,
    "rawOffset": 1,
    "sunset": "2021-08-16 20:29",
    "timezoneId": "Europe/Vienna",
    "dstOffset": 2,
    "countryName": "Austria",
    "time": "2021-08-16 00:55",
    "lat": 47.01
}
```

The key you're looking for seems to be `timezoneId`, not *timezone*.

### Adjusting the Code

Try using

```php
    $output['data'] = $decode['timezoneId'];
```

Comment: @simonjadams did the suggested adjustment solve your problem?